url_launcher doesnt send msg in wp
i am trying to use url_launcher to send my whereabouts to my emergency contact in my app using the following code but its not working could someone help me pls
String locationMessage =
'Emergency! I need help. Here is my current location: https://www.google.com/maps/search/?api=1&query=${position
.latitude},${position.longitude}';
  String phoneNumber = '372990290'; // Replace with your emergency contact's number

  String whatsappUrl = "whatsapp://send?phone=$phoneNumber&text=$locationMessage";


  if (await url_launcher.canLaunchUrl(Uri.parse(whatsappUrl)) ){
    await url_launcher.launchUrl(Uri.parse(whatsappUrl));
  } else {
    throw 'Could not launch $whatsappUrl';
  }
}

} i want it to send the location of the mobile once i press the button but it keeps giving me an error saying component name for the above thing is null hence could not launch whatsappurl how can i resolve it

have you added additional permissions required by url_launcher

You can try below function to send message on WhatsApp
void _shareLocationThroughWhatsApp() async {
  String contact = "91*********";
  String text = 'Emergency! I need help. Here is my current location: https://www.google.com/maps/search/?api=1&query=${position.latitude},${position.longitude}';
  String androidUrl = "whatsapp://send?phone=$contact&text=$text";
  String iosUrl = "https://wa.me/$contact?text=${Uri.parse(text)}";
  String webUrl = 'https://api.whatsapp.com/send/?phone=$contact&text=$text';

  try {
    if (Platform.isIOS) {
      if (await canLaunchUrl(Uri.parse(iosUrl))) {
        await launchUrl(Uri.parse(iosUrl));
      }
    } else {
      if (await canLaunchUrl(Uri.parse(androidUrl))) {
        await launchUrl(Uri.parse(androidUrl));
      }
    }
  } catch(e) {
    await launchUrl(Uri.parse(webUrl), mode: LaunchMode.externalApplication);
  }
}

If the url_launcher is not able to launch the external application on its own, then you must add mode: LaunchMode.externalApplication while launching the URL.
